# Given a table HOUSES, find the euclidean distance between points with largest X and Y coordinate, and the points with the smallest X and Y coordinate

Tags: mysql, data-science, distance

Given a table HOUSES, find the euclidean distance between points with the largest X and Y coordinate, and the points with the smallest X and Y coordinate.

The Euclidean Distance between 2 points P(x1, y1) and Q(x2, y2) is defined as: `sqrt((x1 - x2)2 + (y1 - y2)2)`.

The description of table HOUSES-

```
Field         |  Type
ID            |  INT
OWNER         |  VARCHAR
XCoordinate   |  INT
YCoordinate   |  INT
```

The Query I wrote-

```
SELECT SQRT(POW(MAX(XCoordinate)-MIN(XCoordinate),2)+ POW(MAX(YCoordinate) - MIN(YCoordinate),2)) AS A
FROM HOUSES
```

This query passed the tests for the question, but I am not sure how. How can we guarantee the min XCoordinate and min YCoordinate belong to the same point? Similarly for the coordinates of the other point?
The question is from InterviewBit

Comment: *How can we guarantee the min XCoordinate and min YCoordinate belong to the same point?* Noway to guarantee.

Comment: You would group by the unique identifier of the point

Comment: *between points with the largest X and Y coordinate, and the points with the smallest X and Y coordinate.* The task condition is not correct. It must contain one solid criterium. Now it contains two independent criteria, and there is no any priority for them.

Comment: @Akina you can define a criteria for a point , even for more complex polygons, but the question is too losely worded.

Comment: I believe the table was modeled such that it passed the test case, but if I had to solve it I would order by X,Y get first and last rows, apply join on them and find the result

Comment: @ShubhamDhoundiyal you would have to define what you mean by smallest X and Y coordinates, like adding them up.